# How do I clear the dropdownlist values on button click event using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, button, drop-down-menu, click

How do I clear the dropdownlist values on button click event using jQuery?

Comment: Do you want to reset them to the default (top) value?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A shorter alternative to the first solution given by **Russ Cam** would be:

```
$('#mySelect').val('');
```

This assumes you want to retain the list, but make it so that no option is selected.

If you wish to select a particular default value, just pass that value instead of an empty string.

```
$('#mySelect').val('someDefaultValue');
```

or to do it by the index of the option, you could do:

```
$('#mySelect option:eq(0)').attr('selected','selected'); // Select first option
```

Comment: this is not correct. he wants to clear all options. val(''); doesnt do that, it simpyl clears the selection.  you should use .empty() instead

Answer (score 62):

```
$('#dropdownid').empty();
```

That will remove all `<option>` elements underneath the dropdown element.

If you want to unselect selected items, go with the code from Russ.

Comment: How can i get all the options back after setting the dropdown to empty, note that the dropdown is being populated from database?

Comment: @Piyush: If you want to restore the exact same option, you can just cache those. Like, `var $opts = $('select option').detach();` and then  you can re-insert those later with `$opts.appendTo('#selectID');`

Comment: I get how that clears it, but in my case the selection options were populated from a database based on selection of another dropdown.  So, how do I put the default text there, since the default text was there from pre-ajaxing so to speak so the source shows it but the ajax doesnt.  Just putting `$('#blarg').val('Default Text');` didnt work for me.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to reset the selected options

```
$('select option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
```

If you actually want to **remove** the options (although I don't think you mean this).

```
$('select').empty();
```

Substitute `select` for the most appropriate selector in your case (this may be by id or by CSS class). Using as is will reset all `<select>` elements on the page

Comment: only this one works for me, the other answer above  does NOT works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset bootstrap page with button click using jQuery :

```
function resetForm(){
        var validator = $( "#form_ID" ).validate();
        validator.resetForm();
}
```

Using above code you also have change the field colour as red to normal.

If you want to reset only fielded value then :

```
$("#form_ID")[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the other codes do not work, try `$("#element_id").selectpicker('val', '');`