# ajax call causes duplicate data on subsequent clicks

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a pop-up menu that I select customers from. It is populated with an ajax call and selections are updated on a form. This works fine, however when I click on the `.lookup-cust-hide` a second time the json data (my customer list) repeats itself. I now have two full list of customers concatenated..

I'm thinking I need to clear the ajax call at the end somehow???

javascript:

```
$("#customer .lookup-cust-hide").click(function() {
        $("#contactdiv1").css("display", "block");

        $.ajax({                                      
            url: 'customer_fill.php',                         
            data: {action:"invoice"},                                             
            dataType: 'json',                   
            success: function(data){
                populateSelectBoxes($('#contactdiv1 #dropdown'), data);

                function populateSelectBoxes($select, data) {
                    var customers = [];
                    $.each(data, function() {
                        customers.push('<li data-value="'+this.autonum+'">' + this.customer + '</li>');
                    });
                    $select.append(customers.join(''));
                }

                function populateTableRow($tableBody, data, selectedCustomerAutonum) {
                    var customers;
                    $.each(data, function() {
                        if (this.autonum == selectedCustomerAutonum) {
                            customers = this;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    $($tableBody).val(customers.customer+ '\n' + customers.address1 + '\n' + customers.address2 + '\n' + customers.address3);
                }

                $('#contactdiv1 #dropdown li').click(function(e) {
                    var selection = $(this).attr("data-value");
                    $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
                    populateTableRow($('#customer-title'), data, selection);
                });


            }
        }); 
    });

    $("#contact #cancel").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });
```

Comment: yes clear the selection box, also you can cache the ajax call if you like

Comment: How do I clear the box?

Comment: $('select').empty();     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985072/how-do-i-clear-the-dropdownlist-values-on-button-click-event-using-jquery

Comment: my select box is not actually a `<select>` element - its a `<ul>` and I have tried: `$('#dropdown').empty();`to empty the `<ul>` but that didn't work?

Comment: Have you tried changing this? $select.append(customers.join(''));

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/c90ugjce/  empty() works fine

Comment: I'm not sure I was putting it in the right place - wanted it in the cancel button click event, bit that didn't work. Moved it to the bottom of my `populateTableRow` function and that works, not sure thats the best place as it is nit or miss, sometimes it loads multiple list and other times it works as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add:

```
$("#contact #cancel").click(function() {
    $('ul').empty();
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

...and final results:

```
$("#customer .lookup-cust-hide").click(function() {
    $("#contactdiv1").css("display", "block");

    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'customer_fill.php',                         
        data: {action:"invoice"},                                             
        dataType: 'json',                   
        success: function(data){
            populateSelectBoxes($('#contactdiv1 #dropdown'), data);

            function populateSelectBoxes($select, data) {
                var customers = [];
                $.each(data, function() {
                    customers.push('<li data-value="'+this.autonum+'">' + this.customer + '</li>');
                });
                $select.append(customers.join(''));
            }

            function populateTableRow($tableBody, data, selectedCustomerAutonum) {
                var customers;
                $.each(data, function() {
                    if (this.autonum == selectedCustomerAutonum) {
                        customers = this;
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                $($tableBody).val(customers.customer+ '\n' + customers.address1 + '\n' + customers.address2 + '\n' + customers.address3);
            }

            $('#contactdiv1 #dropdown li').click(function(e) {
                var selection = $(this).attr("data-value");
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
                populateTableRow($('#customer-title'), data, selection);
                $('ul').empty();
            });

        }
    }); 
});

$("#contact #cancel").click(function() {
    $('ul').empty();
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```