# Clearing all items in a dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to clear all items in a dropdown using jquery ? I will have to clear all items before i call the following method to avoid duplication

```
   $('#drpeventproducts').append($('<option>', {
                        value: data.id,
                        text: itemname
                    }));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clear the dropdownlist values on button click event using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985072/how-do-i-clear-the-dropdownlist-values-on-button-click-event-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can just do below. That will remove all the options under the select with id "drpeventproducts"

```
$('#drpeventproducts').html('');
```

or

```
$('#drpeventproducts').empty();
```

```js
$('#drpeventproducts').html('');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drpeventproducts"><option value="1">1</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824/how-do-you-remove-all-the-options-of-a-select-box-and-then-add-one-option-and-se) link

```
$('#drpeventproducts')
        .find('option')
        .remove()
        .end()
        .append($('<option>', {
              value: data.id,
              text: itemname
        }));
```

Comment: I can't find flag option for this question or maybe not allowed